# Why codevision avr ignores some statements in "if" operator?

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, avr

Now it is works as it should.
 Well,certanly it was a my mistake,but without some
 of your questions itwould be difficult to get rid with it.

```
   if ((key==11)^(key==13)^(key==16)^(key==17))   //this is the only 
                              // dirty hack style string needed to fix this
        {  
            switch (key)
                { 
                     case 11: { mode=0x01; break; }  //plus
                     case 13: { mode=0x02; break; }  //minus 
                     case 16: { mode=0x03; break; } //multiply
                     case 17: { mode=0x04; break; } //divide
                }  

            if (mode)
                {  
                      buffer=atof(display);  
                      firstop=1;  
                      first=1;   
                      redraw=1; 
                                      //and to delete the goto
                }   
        }
```

Comment: The code is not complete. please show us the definitions of the variables.

Comment: BTW: using `goto`is considered bad practice. Why not just put `//some other code here` into the else branch? Also your indentation is horrible.

Comment: I can't put `//some other code here` into the else branch because `//some other code here` should to execute in both cases (if _(mode)_ and if _(!mode)_). Anyway,i tryed to remove `//some other code here`as it is not required by current part of code and it is still not working.
 This is the definitions of the variables

Comment: `static bit redraw=1;   //this
static bit first=1;    //and this
static bit firstop=0;  //and this
unsigned char mode=0x00;   //and this `

Comment: Ok,i added the definitions of the variables and changed code for the current state in my project. Please execuse my bad spelling,maybe it is the cause of some misunderstandings.

Comment: what is with the rest of the definitions? c'mon there is so much stuff missing. how should the error be spotted? My guess is some ISR issue or some buffer overflow. You also have not said that is not working. Does it crash? I didn't got the 'places' thing. Is there something missing? please remove the comments that does not match any longer.

Comment: "Is not working" means that when i press digits to type first operand,then press the operation button,type the second operand and then pres equal button is nothing happens. Is still displaying the number that displayed before i pressed equal.

Comment: And finally,i find out the mistake.It was a simple logic mistake,i forgot that after the equal key pressing,the _mode_ is still > 0. This is for the further euqaling without pressing the operation button and selecting the operands. Just like you pres **5** then **+** then **1** and repeating the **=** you will get **6**,**7**,**8** etc.Now i will update my post and show what exactly i changed. Yes,it is a pretty dirty hack but it is only for making sure what is mistake was.

Comment: Now it is working and i can change my code to be more elegant without any hacks.Thank you wery much for you helping,your questions helped me to find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You never reset mode, so pressing it once will keep doing the selected mode for any other key.

You define no default statement in your switch statement

Try to play with the compiler optimization switches. If it solves your problem, then it is probably a `volatile` problem where mode gets optimized out

Comment: Ok,i never reset mode.But it is checked only if i press the equal button,so i can change mode by pressing the other operation button.